# How can i fix this error in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to register for a Google account automatically using the Selenium library and WebDriver. The code registers the email and then the password. this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

email = input('Enter email : ')
password = input('Enter password : ')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()) , options = options)
driver.get('https://google.com')

first_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='gb_Dd']")))
first_click.click()

second_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='identifierId']")))
second_click.send_keys('email')
second_click.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

third_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Passwd']")))
third_click.send_keys('password')
third_click.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

but when I write this line of code (the part responsible for registering the password)

```
third_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='password']")))
third_click.send_keys('password')
third_click.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

this error appears

```
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13004/2901393778.py in <module>
     27 
     28 third_click = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Passwd']")))
---> 29 third_click.send_keys(password)
     30 third_click.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    229                 value = "\n".join(remote_files)
    230 
--> 231         self._execute(
    232             Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {"text": "".join(keys_to_typing(value)), "value": keys_to_typing(value)}
    233         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    393             params = {}
    394         params["id"] = self._id
--> 395         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    396 
    397     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None) -> WebElement:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    344         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    345         if response:
--> 346             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    347             response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    348             return response

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    243                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    244             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 245         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.89)
Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00C7CE93+45171]
    (No symbol) [0x00C090E1]
    (No symbol) [0x00AFBCE0]
    (No symbol) [0x00B2B678]
    (No symbol) [0x00B2ACCA]
    (No symbol) [0x00B4B04C]
    (No symbol) [0x00B27FA6]
    (No symbol) [0x00B4B2C4]
    (No symbol) [0x00B5DCFA]
    (No symbol) [0x00B4AE46]
    (No symbol) [0x00B2675E]
    (No symbol) [0x00B278FD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F35499+2897529]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F7DC4B+3194411]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F77A21+3169281]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00D06110+606960]
    (No symbol) [0x00C12E5C]
    (No symbol) [0x00C0EFE8]
    (No symbol) [0x00C0F10F]
    (No symbol) [0x00C01807]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76CEFCC9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x778B7B1E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x778B7AEE+238]
```

I tried a lot to solve this problem, but in the end I was unable

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, it wasn't showing me the exception, which you have shown.
Nonetheless, you have to add one more wait after `presence_of_element_located`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='Passwd']")))
```

because seems like, element was displaying but was not intractable, so I have added that.